# Restart Loop At Last Read Row

Tags: excel, loops, vbscript, msgbox

I'm running a loop to read data from Excel and when I receive an error my script stops and gives me an `vbAbortRetryIgnore` option within a `MsgBox`.  If I get an error, I want to be able to restart the loop at the beginning of that row that it stopped on with the "Retry" button or skip that row and go to the next row with the "Ignore" button.

My original loop is as follows:

```
Sub Main
    subGoToScreen "DELP", "********", "0000000001"
    Dim rw
    TITLE = "DELP Script"
    rw = 2
    Do While oExcelObject.CountA(oExcelSheet.Rows(rw)) > 0
        subDoWork oExcelSheet.Rows(rw)
        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Then if I receive an error like this `Len(rw.Cells(1).Value) < 8` then if "Retry" is chosen, I'd like to go back to the first cell in that row restart the loop.  I'm using this loop if "Retry" is chosen:

```
Sub MainRetry
    Dim rw
    TITLE = "DELP Script"
    rw = oExcelSheet.Rows(rw).Cells(1)

    Do While oExcelObject.CountA(oExcelSheet.Rows(rw)) > 0
        subDoWork oExcelSheet.Rows(rw)
        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

It doesn't work and gives me a run time error.  Does anyone know how to identify the current row I'm reading, remember that row and re-read the row or move to the next row?  Currently, without the 2nd loop it picks back up reading the sheet at `rw.Cells(2).Value`.

Comment: How is `rw = oExcelSheet.Rows(rw).Cells(1)` meant to work? You specify a variable of `rw` before it is assigned. Did you intend to pass through the row index that was reached before the error occurred, at the moment `rw` is declared locally and you pass no argument in so it will never work as you expect.

Comment: yes, that is correct.  for the retry, I was intending to begin back at the beginning of the row before the error occurred.

Comment: Lankymart thanks for pushing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it working:

I defined a `CurrentRow` and a `LastRow` as follows:

```
CurrentRow          = rw.Cells(8).Row
LastRow             = CurrentRow - 1
```

Then I created two new sub-procedures, one to handle a retry and one to handle an ignore and set the starting point for the retry as `rw = LastRow + 1` and the ignore as `rw = CurrentRow + 1` while using the same loop

```
Do While oExcelObject.CountA(oExcelSheet.Rows(rw)) > 0
    subDoWork oExcelSheet.Rows(rw)
    rw = rw + 1
Loop
```